# New Mailing error "SAVEPOINT civi_0 does not exist"

Tags: mailing

PATH(civicrm/a/#/mailing/new)
When I input data, the system will save data, and after save, "SAVEPOINT civi_0 does not exist" appears in the message box on the right. I have installed the latest version of DRUAPL and CIVICRM. Why are there always so many problems?

Answer (score 1):

I've found this discussion in the issue logs and a solution that appears to work (enable patching in composer):

https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/2198